# How do I run a NodeJS script in typescript with create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, create-react-app, ts-node

I have an app I created with create-react-app, using the following versions:

- Node `v16.15.1`
- Typescript `v4.3.2`
- react-scripts `v4.0.3` (though I am open to answers that require react-scripts `v5`)

I want to compile and run an executable NodeJS script written in Typescript using the same configuration as the React App. Additionally, I need to be able to **import files from the rest of the app** into my script.

e.g. /src/scripts/myscript.ts

```
import foo from '../util/foo'

const result = foo(process.argv[2])

console.log(result)
```

The closest I have gotten is:

```bash
npx ts-node --esm src/scripts/myscript.ts
```

However it only works if I add `"type": "module"` to my package.json, which breaks `npm start`. Even then, my script breaks on the `export` keyword.

I can create a `package.json` in the `scripts` folder with `"type": "module"` and a `tsconfig` that extends the app config:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": false,
    "outDir": "build"
  }
}
```

But this runs into issues with import/export in the imported typescript files.

If react-scripts has the correct config to compile and run Typescript files in its `start` and `build` scripts, how do I run a custom script?

Comment: I don't think that's going to be at all straightforward - CRA uses Babel and Webpack under the hood, and doesn't emit JS in a form you could require in your script.

Comment: I use a mono repo created with lerna -- node js scripts are in a separate package with their own ts config.